# Выкинуть с результатов группировки символы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Могут быть три варианта строки:
1) вот "такая" строка
2) вот 'такая' строка
3) вот <РР такая> строка
Нужно чтобы в matches[1] попадало соответственно ", ', или РР (без стрелочки).
Как модифицировать шаблон?

```
/( " | ' | <\w+ )/x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
/( " | ' | (?<=<)\w+ )/x
           ^^^^^^
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Z7OvJQ/1/).

Блок предварительного просмотра назад `(?<=<)` проверяет наличие знака `<` прямо перед `РР`, но не добавляет к извлекаемой подстроке.

Comment: единственное, что когда я его вставляю в полное регулярное выражение, оно не срабатывает

Comment: @SanyaH Ну, а где же это ваше выражение в вопросе?

Comment: вот так полное выглядит `\w+\s*=\s* ("|'|(?<=<)\w+) `, которое не срабатывает

Comment: @SanyaH Естественно, не сработает. Нельзя захватить в одну группу непоследовательные символы. Используйте `\w+\s*=\s*(["']|<\w+)`, а потом удалите `<` с помощью отдельной строчки кода.

Comment: то, что захватывается идет последовательно?
В одном из шаблонов мне нужно сделать такую логику - слово, далее возможен(ы) пробел(ы), далее знак равенства, опять возможен(ы) пробел(ы), после чего идет последовательность кавычка (или двойная кавычка, или <РР) и слово. Если после знака равенства в шаблоне указать возможность там наличия любого символа, то все работает, но нужен контроль какраз отсутствия там чего либо, кроме пробела(ов)   `\w+\s*=.* ( " | ' | (?<=<)\w+ )`